# Why doesn't this vector print?

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, iterator, auto

The compile error says `it` was not declared in this scope, it does not name a type, expected `;`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;

    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(3);
    vec.push_back(5);

    for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
         cout << *it << endl;
    }

    cout << "size: " << vec.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works fine: http://ideone.com/qVFl6p. Did you specify -std=c++11 ?

Comment: Yes thank you, I had it set before must of not saved, it works now though!

Comment: Would you like to fix your indentation?

Comment: I indented it like that because I was having trouble posting the code.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, you need to specify the `-std=c++11` flag when compiling.

Just to mention an alternative syntax for iterating, the [range-for statement](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#for):

```
for (auto& i: vec)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

and for populating a `vector` with initial values using [uniform initialization](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init):

```
std::vector<int> vec {1, 3, 5};
```

---

Also see [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Comment: why auto& and not just auto? I'm new to C++.

Comment: @SalRosa to take a reference to the element of the container. It really should be ``const auto&``, since you are not modifying the element inside the loop.